# Need to set "display; none" with CSS for placeholder <div class="sticky-element-placeholder sticky-element-active"

Tags: html, css

Wordpress - Elementor. Trying to optimize code something went wrong and now I got this giant empty space above my first section on the page that I'm trying to get rid of. I'm a newbie and using Elementor so I only have the custom css to work with. The problem manifests on tablet and mobile, not desktop.

```
<div class="sticky-element-placeholder sticky-element-active" style="display:flex; float:none; flex:0 1 auto; box-sizing:border-box; clear:none; overflow:visible; transform:none; width:448.09722900390625px; height:3277.34716796875px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;"></div>
```

I've tried targeting the following without any success.

```
.sticky-element-placeholder.sticky-element-active {
    display: none
}

<div class="sticky-element-placeholder sticky-element-active" style="display:flex; float:none; flex:0 1 auto; box-sizing:border-box; clear:none; overflow:visible; transform:none; width:448.09722900390625px; height:3277.34716796875px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;"></div>
```

Comment: Because you have an inline style!

Comment: I believed that happened when I tried to make the page faster using plugins. Is there any way I can fix this now?

Answer (score 0):

use important to your style.

```
.sticky-element-placeholder.sticky-element-active {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that the following code<br/> 

.sticky-element-placeholder.sticky-element-active {
    display: none!important; <br/>
<br/>
messes up my site a bit and it would be better to resize the placeholder height in some way. I've tried the following but didn't work for some reason.<br/>

.sticky-element-placeholder.sticky-element-active {
    height: 200!important;
}



}  been trying to use

Comment: if this class is similar to other code your web must messed up. try to use an id for it and then use display: none. that wont cause any side effect